# django rest framework - global default model serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

In short, I want to have a global default serializer per model. My use case here is to create dynamic serializer- i.e creating `ModelSerializer` classes on the fly.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   # many more fields..

class CustomerTicket(models.Model):
   customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
   date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   # more fields..
```

Customer will be referenced by many other models, and hence it will be serialized as a nested object. I don't want the 'code' field to appear in the output - no matter what it should always be excluded.

Now I'd like to create a function:

```
def serialize_default(model, fields, queryset):
    class S(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = model 
            fields = fields
            depth = 1
    return S(queryset, many=True)
```

if I serialize `CustomerTicket` queryset using this function, I will get all the customer fields as a nested object. I know I can override it locally, but I want to define a CustomerSerializer that will be used by default (for the nested Customer here) unless other serializer is specified as a field. How to achieve this?

Comment: Would you accept to have all your serializers inherit a mixin? To my knowledge, there's no way to define global behavior on serializers without making them inherit some custom class of yours.

Comment: That would be fine, I actually thought to override methods in the ModelSerializer class or pass hooks, couldn't find how in the docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like that work for you?

```
class DefaultCustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # whatever fields you want


class DefaultCustomerSerializerModel(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    customer = DefaultCustomerSerializer()


# You can inherit from this to have default customer serializer 
# on serializers you want.

class CustomerTicketSerializer(DefaultCustomerSerializerModel): 

    # Other fields
```

Comment: Is it possible to avoid creating two classes for each model?

Comment: Sure, you can put the ModelSerializer into the mixin (making it a base class rather than a mixin). See my updated version.

Comment: Works, I will use this. Would happy to see another way which doesn't involve a mixin, I'm thinking maybe mapping between model class and serializer class, but I will need a hook for the serialization process